# How can I be certain that the computer I'm using can run a 64-bit OS?

Tags: 64-bit, operating-systems

Specs aside (from a website or other source). What can I do to to be certain my laptop can run a 64-bit OS (ie. Windows 7 64bit)

I've downloaded SiSoft Sandra and I'm not 100% on what stats to read from there. It stated on the processor page that AMD64/EM64T Technology is available.. But on IA64 Technology it says it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run a 64-bit OS definitely if your processor supports AMD64/EMT64.

IA64 is a holdover 64-bit architecture from the Intel Itanium class of processors - designed for servers. It is somewhat considered outmoded now.

Answer (score 2):

There are two differing 64 bit technologies, AMD64/EM64T (often referred as x64) and ia64. ia64 is primarily for server processors like the Intel Itanium, whilst x64 is more popular for desktop and laptop processors including yours, from what you've said.

From what you've said, you should be able to run Windows 7 x64, but you might not get any benefits unless you have 4Gb of RAM or more. There are still some devices that still don't have x64 drivers, such as some digital cameras, and you might need to check availability of those first.